# javascript in to add dynamic list using drop box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript to add a dynamic list using dropbox. In the first dropbox it works fine

[image]

but in the second it only gives one item as shown

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var postURL = "<?php echo url('/admin/service/{{$cust_id}}'); ?>";
    var i=1;

    $('#addstructural').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#structural_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><select class="form-control " name= "structural[]"><option >اختار مهندس  </option>  @foreach($Infrastructuredesigners as $Service)<option value="{{ $Service->id }}">{{ $Service->name}}</option></td>@endforeach </select></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_removes">X</button></td></tr>');

 i++;

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_removes', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    });

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url:postURL,
                method:"POST",
                data:$('#add_namestructural').serialize(),
                type:'json',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data.error){
                        printErrorMsg(data.error);
                    }else{
                        i=1;
                        $('.dynamic-added').remove();
                        $('#add_namestructural')[0].reset();
                        $(".print-success-msg").find("ul").html('');
                        $(".print-success-msg").css('display','block');
                        $(".print-error-msg").css('display','none');
                        $(".print-success-msg").find("ul").append('<li>Record Inserted Successfully.</li>');
                    }
                }
        });
    });

    function printErrorMsg (msg) {
        $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
        $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');
        $(".print-success-msg").css('display','none');
        $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
        });
    }
    });


</script>
```

The above is my javascript which leads to the above mentioned errors. adding this sentence to get this question posted.

Comment: Are you trying to populate the dropdown element with data from your database table?

Comment: I found some serious script errors. get the code checked with an online JS checker like https://prettier.io/playground/

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)`? Is it returning more than one thing?